# Why is the validation accuracy coming to be the baseline accuracy

Tags: efficientnet

I am using EfficientNetB0 for custom training . I get the **following output**

[image]

In order to debug I tried the same data for train and test and get the **following error**

[image]

This is not happening with other networks like Xception and Inception. What can be the reason ?
PS I have displayed only 4 epoch cases but have actually tried out up to 30 and the same problem.
I am pasting a picture of the predictions also. **They are the same in each row**

[image]

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.